# check uncheck All checkboxes not working for all pages when using datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, datatable

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
        $("#result").dataTable({ 
            "scrollX" : true, 
                "ordering" : true,
                "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                "info" : true, 
                });
        });  
    $("#all").click(function () { 
        if ($("#all").is(':checked')) {
            $(".checkboxclass").each(function () {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            }); 
        } else {
            $(".checkboxclass").each(function () {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<table class="tg" id="result" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="tg" style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" id="all" 
                onclick="toggle(this);" /></th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="map : ${listID}">
            <td class="tg bg" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclass" name="check"
                th:id="${map['ID']}" th:value="${map['ID']}" /></td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Checking on one check box selects all but only limited to current page. It is not working for rest of the pages in pagination

Can anyone help on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: You mean it works for first page but does not work for other pages? and you want it to work for every page or all records in pagination ?

Comment: It works for first page. I want to get it work for all page (all record in the table )

Comment: every page  and all records are different?

Comment: why both `$(document).ready(function() {` _and_ `$(function(){` inside? Seems rather unnessecary to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
if ($("#all").is(':checked')) { 
  $(".checkboxclass", table.fnGetNodes()).each(function () { 
  $(this).prop("checked", true);
  });     
else {
  $(".checkboxclass", table.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {
  $(this).prop("checked", false); 
  })
  }
```

Comment: Glad to know this worked for you.  Just so you know you do not have to use each method -- jQuery uses it internally on a collection -- and the if statement.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your additional helpful information. I thought only `each` is actually fetching each and every record inside table.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 4):

Quite likely, you have duplicate IDs; if you have more than one element with the same ID, for example `id="all"`, that gives rise to invalid HTML and you cannot predict how different browsers may handle that. Most will usually pick the first, and ignore the rest of the elements.

Please change:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="all" onclick="toggle(this);" />
```

To:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="all" ....
```

So that your code would be:

```
$(".all").on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('table').find('.checkboxclass').prop('checked', this.checked ); 
});
```

**UPDATE**

*Thanks for clarifying; I'll leave the above so that your comments where you've clarified this may remain relevant*

Here is how you may resolve that issue:

```
    $(function(){
        var table = $("#result").dataTable({ 
            "scrollX" : true, 
                "ordering" : true,
                "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                "info" : true, 
                });
        });  
        $("#all").on('click', function () { 
            var cells = table.api().cells().nodes();
            $( cells ).find('.checkboxclass').prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
    //source: https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/22728/datatables-1-10-select-all-checkbox-and-hidden-rows-pages
```

**Please note** that `$(document).ready(function() { .... });` and `$(function() { .... });` are different ways of writing the same thing -- no need to nest them.

Comment: Thanks for replying. id="all" is only for header of te table and it occurs only once. It  will not be repeated. On clicking of id="all", it will check all rows in the table. But when using with datatable, it is not checking rows that are in other pages of pagination

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean. Let me check what the documentation.

Comment: @Java_User, please let me know if the updated answer is of any help.

Comment: I have tried your solution. I got error `table is not a function`. Then I placed click event of `#all` inside function . Then i got error `table.cells is not a function`. I am not able to resolve this error.

Comment: It should have been `var cells = table.api().cells().nodes();` see correction and give it another try.

Comment: Thankyou for reply. `table.fnGetNodes()` worked for me and I posted as answer too.

Answer (score 0):

you have declared on click toggle function but it is not used. please find the code snippet it helpful to sort out ur issue.

```
<table class="tg" id="result" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="tg" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="checkbox" id="all" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg bg" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclass" name="check" /></td>
            <td class="tg bg" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclass" name="check" /></td>
            <td class="tg bg" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclass" name="check" /></td>
            <td class="tg bg" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclass" name="check" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

 $("#all").click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.checkboxclass').each(function () {
            this.checked = true;
        })
    }
    else {
        $('.checkboxclass').each(function () {
            this.checked = false;
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This again check all checkboxes only in page1 of all paginations. I guess the issue is with datatable not with jquery. Because it is not able to find checkboxes in the rest of the pages

Comment: do you want state maintenance for every page action ?

Comment: Yes. The values should be retained.

Comment: ok . please try it, you have to stored the last state in your local storage , it maintain the value untill refresh the browser

Comment: Table will have thousands of records, displaying first 10 in first page and the remaining in next pages using datatable. The functionality is, when user clicks `export` button, they can check all records which should fetch records from hidden paginated section also.